# CSS styles for input elements named dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
    <input type="text" id="email[1]" name="email[1]"> 
    <input type="text" id="email[2]" name="email[2]">
.
.
```

That's been populated using php. Inside a for loop there's:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='email[".$i."]' name='email[".$i."]'> ";
```

As I don't know the number of inputs  that are going to be created, how can I give styles to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are all going to have the same style, you could use classes. For example:

```
echo "<input type='text' class='emailinput' id='email[".$i."]' name='email[".$i."]' /> ";
```

And in the CSS you can style the elements like this:

```
.emailinput
{
    width:              20px;
    background-color:   red;
}
```

By the way, I have added a slash to the end of the input element. This is for XHTML valid code. You should do this for all input elements (`/>`).

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<input class="anything you want" ... />
```

CSS:

```
.anything {
...
}
.you {
...
}
.want {
...
}
```